# Change Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, where-clause

I have two dataframes.  I want to change some of the values.

I know how to change it on a one by one basis, using isin and where statement but I don't know how to change a large list of changes.

df1

```
 Name      Type
 David     Staff 
 Jones     Pilot
 Jack      Pilot
 Susan     Steward
 John      Staff
 Leroy     Staff
 Steve     Staff
```

df2

```
 Name     Type
 David    Captain
 Leroy    Pilot
 Steve    Pilot
```

How do I change the "type" column on df1 by using df2?

df_desired

```
 Name      Type
 David     Captain 
 Jones     Pilot
 Jack      Pilot
 Susan     Steward
 John      Staff
 Leroy     Pilot
 Steve     Pilot
```

Comment: you use a dictionary in your code with multiple key value pairs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try map `Type` column of `df2` to `df1` then `update`

```py
df1['Type'].update(df1['Name'].map(df2.set_index('Name')['Type']))
```

```
print(df1)

    Name     Type
0  David  Captain
1  Jones    Pilot
2   Jack    Pilot
3  Susan  Steward
4   John    Staff
5  Leroy    Pilot
6  Steve    Pilot
```

Comment: thanks, this is much more elegant than me joining the dataframe then replacing columns.

Comment: when I try to use the solution, for values, that don't have a value from df2.  It creates a nan value in df1 now.  How can I make it so that the values where there is nothing in df2 to remain as is?

Comment: @OptimusPrime Could you provide some examples? `update` only updates the non-NaN value.

Comment: my dictionary has values that are not included in the main df.  how can this work.  It says "reindexing only valid with uniquely index objects"

Comment: @OptimusPrime It seems your `df2['Name']` has duplicated value, in this case, which one do you want to keep?

Comment: @ynjxjmh can i keep the first one?

Comment: @OptimusPrime You can try `df2.drop_duplicates().set_index`.